# Multiple signal handlers in a C++ appllication

Tags: linux, signals, handler

I am working on a C++ application running on Linux. The application has several sets of signal handlers that interfere with each other. My task is to understand how those handlers are set and put them in order. I am familiar with some of them and need to find all others. I tried to search the source code for words like 'signal' and 'sigaction' but could not find any handler that I am not aware of.

What can be other ways to find those handlers?

Is there any way to see/trace installing of those handlers during run time?

Comment: They might be used by libraries. You could `strace` your application to understand what it is installing signals. Read absolutely [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and tell us more about your application: do you have all its source code, and all the source codes of libraries; is it loading plugins thru [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)?

Comment: I have already run strace. It showed multiple calls for rt_sigaction(). It does not show where the call came, though.
The applications is very large. It consists of several modules (total number of files is several thousands). It works with several 3rd party tools like Oracle, ACE, etc. We do have source code of some of them and I have access to whole set of our source code files. Each module is a shared library. Some of them linked to the executable while others are loaded thru dlopen()

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Is there any way to see/trace installing of those handlers during run time?
> ```

You can set a breakpoint on sigaction() function and print the backtrace when the breakpoint is reached.

ADDED: as commented, some code might use signal() function to set up signal handler so you may also trace that function.

Comment: I tried setting a breakpoint on both calls. Did not show a thing.

Comment: @Michael Try setting a breakpoint on `main` first. When it hits, set breakpoints on `signal` and `sigaction`.

Comment: Did it. Did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) with a `NULL` second `act` argument and a non `NULL` third `oldact` argument to query (i.e. examine) the signal handling of a given `signum`, the first argument to `sigaction`:

```
 struct sigaction oldactst;
 memset (&oldactst, 0, sizeof(oldactst));
 if (sigaction (signum, NULL, &oldactst))) {
    perror("examining sigaction"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 // do something with oldactst
```

Then perhaps use a debugger, or [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html), to transform the address into a reasonable name.... Don't forget to link your entire application with `-rdynamic` (and if possible compile it with `-g`, i.e. with debugging information)...

Read also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) as I commented...

See also `/proc/self/status` or `/proc/$PID/status` (e.g. [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...)

Comment: Your proposition gives address instead of function/method name that I need.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to understand what happens by creating my own signal() and sigaction() calls. They do nothing but print stack trace when called. Since they appear in my code, they shadow the real ones and I can see all the places where signal handlers are set. I used backtrace() call family for stack printing.
Thank all who helped.